# How to validate at least one Checkbox is checked using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hear is my code:

```
<div class="reminderDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="require-one" id="lmrText"  name="lmrText"><label>Text Message</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" class="require-one" id="lmrPhone" name="lmrPhone"><label>Phone</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="require-one" id="lmrEmail" name="lmrEmail"><label>Email</label>
</div>
```

Using JQuery, how can I determine if at least one checkbox is selected?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".reminderDiv :checked").length > 0
```

This will be `true` if at least one checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('.require-one:checked').length > 0)
{
   // at least one checkbox was checked
}
else
{
  // no checkbox was checked
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw6Kq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')==true) {
    alert("Your data");
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')==true)`? Or, more colloquially, `if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked'))`?

Comment: @pickypg I just considered false for client side validation purpose.

Comment: That's a very valid point and use, but without noting that in your answer, then it answers a different question. I suspect that he is using the opposite result (`true`) to do client side development before allowing someone to pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.require-one:checked').size() === 0){
{
    //your code here
}
```